# Stateless or Stateful?

Tags: flutter

I tried to create a simple form to validate user input data.

```
class UserForm extends StatelessWidget {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
    
    UserForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
                TextFormField(
                    controller: usernameController,
                    validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter something';
                        }
                        return null;
                    },
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                        print(usernameController.text);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Check'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

When I type something and delete it after, I get the error message "Please enter something under the textfield".

I saw an official demo example with a form validation here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation.

Now, my question is: why do we need a StatefulWidget for a form, if the error message gets displayed in a StatelessWidget. The value of TextFormField is changing, not the custom form widget I created.

Can somebody explain me when to use stateless and when stateful?

Comment: Textfields should be in stateFull Widget

Comment: @GHPrakash Ok, but why?

Comment: Your Question is about why the documentation used stateful widget for forms or Is it okay to use textfields in Statelesswidget ?

Comment: @Balaji The question is: why would you use a stateful widget for a form if all you do is input data in some textformfields and validate them?

Comment: @Ghost because the text data is stored inside TextEditingController not the fields themselves when you provide controller parameter. And stateless widget will lost controller data when the tree rebuilds. I've written detailed answer below if you're interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use stateless or stateful widget for hosting your form widgets. The state will be preserved in those fields themselves.

But there's a catch. If you need to access those fields' content or control them you'll need to use `TextEditingController`. Of course you can instantiate `TextEditingController` inside your stateless widget but when your widget tree updates the text controller will be re-instantiated, so all data will be lost inside it (cursor position and text value).

So, to preserve controller state you have to create it inside stateful widget or use some sort of state management or dependency injection to store it somewhere that'll survive the next update.

Also `TextEditingController` could lead to memory leaks in your app, so it's best advice to destroy them after you've used it. You can do this by overriding `dispose` method of `State` class.

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

#### Conclusion

Use `State` class whenever you need to persist a value / variable. The widget class will be re-created after each build so all the values inside it will be lost (or will cause memory leak if not cleaned in proper way) and replaced with a new instance. The update doesn't happens regularly so the chance of happening this low but if the parent widget that's hosting your form widget changes its state then the updates will affect the form widget will be rebuilt as well.

In general widgets are just scaffold for your widget tree. They should just hold immutable data and when you need to change it you have to use mutable `State` or use another state management approach. When you use `StatefulWidget` the instance of your `State` class will be carried over to the "next frame" where new instance of your widget could use the state that's holding data from "previous frame" to render the UI.

#### References

Check out the links below if you're interested in learning more:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Stateless or stateful widgets all depends on your requirement. Taking your example, If your requirement is just to validate input text then your example is perfect. Think if you want to display the entered text in a Text widget, then you should move to stateful widget.

In summary if you want change the UI according user interaction then use a stateful widget and just to display things without handling changes use stateless widget like Text, Icon etc [Official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#stateful-and-stateless-widgets)

You may wonder then how the validator in you example displays error because it is inside a stateless widget. That's because `TextFormField` is a statefulwidget and changes the UI according to the user interaction.

official documentation shows the `form` in a stateful because in most cases forms need to be in stateful widget because it's need to modify the UIs according to user inputs. **Form keys** is a another major reason to use a stateful widget. Without a stateful widget it is hard to idenify a form uniquely in a widget tree using **form keys**.

Answer (score -1):

It should be stateful, as it's not only about `TextFormField`, but we generally have others widget as well, which `enable/disable` based on the `TextFormField` contains values or not.

Example:

```
bool _btnEnabled = false;


  TextFormField(

    ...
    autovalidate: true,
    validator: (String txt){
      if (txt.length == 10){
        setState((){
          _btnEnabled = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState((){
          _btnEnabled = false;
        });
      }
    }

    ...

  FlatButton(
    onPressed: _btnEnabled == true ? yourCallback : null,
    child: ...
```